# JavaFX Displaying Words in Ascending Order

Tags: java, javafx

I've done something wrong here because I have no errors, but this program I           wrote won't run. Please help to get this to run according to description below.

Program Description: Using JavaFX: Write a program that reads words from a        text file and displays all the words (duplicates allowed) in ascending     alphabetical order.The words must start with a letter. The text file is passed as a command-line argument. The text file I'm to use is called: *example20_1.txt* and there is to be an input box for the file and submit button, the file results are to be displayed in an input window below the box and button. This is what I have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public class DisplayingWords extends Application {

   TextField fileName = new TextField();
   Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
   TextArea outputArea = new TextArea();

   public void main() {
       submitButton.setOnAction(e -> {
           if(fileName.getText().length() > 0) {
               submitButtonClick();
           }
       });
   }

   public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       // Check command-line parameter usage
       if (args.length > 0) {
           fileName.setText(args[0]);

           System.out.println("Source file: " + fileName.getText());
       }

       main();
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       try {
           BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

           Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
       scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

           primaryStage.show();

           // Set the stage title
           primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise20_01");

           // Place the scene in the stage
           primaryStage.setScene(scene);

           // Display the stage
           primaryStage.show();

           // Hold a button in an HBox
           HBox inputBox = new HBox();
           inputBox.setSpacing(10);
           inputBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
           inputBox.getChildren().addAll(new Text("Filename:"));
           inputBox.getChildren().addAll(fileName);
           inputBox.getChildren().addAll(submitButton);
           root.setTop(inputBox);

           //This creates a text box to display the results
           //from reading the file in a pane
           outputArea.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
           outputArea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey");
           root.setCenter(outputArea);
       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }


   public void submitButtonClick() {
       if(fileName.getText().length() > 0) {
//           File sourceFile = new File(fileName.getText());
//           if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
//               System.out.println("Source file " + fileName.getText()
//                   + " does not exist");
//           }
       }

       fileName.setText("Test 1");
   }

   class SortFile
   {
       //sorting function
   void sortArray(String array[]) {
       //Loop for no.of passes
   for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++)

       //Repeat no.of comparisons
       for(int j=0;j<array.length-i-1;j++)

           //Comparing adjacent elements
           if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1])>0)
   {
               //Swap using temp variable
               String temp=array[j];
               array[j]=array[j+1];
               array[j+1]=temp;
              }
   }
   public void main(String args[])
   {
       //Creating File object
       File freader;

       //Scanner for reading
       Scanner filescanner;

       //Array list for dynamic elements adding
   ArrayList <String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

   //If file name is no.of passed as argument is 1
   if(args.length==1)
   {
   try
   {
       //Create file object
       freader = new File(args[0]);

       //Reading from file
       filescanner = new Scanner(freader);

       //Reading until end of file
   while(filescanner.hasNext())
   {
       //Reading each word and to Array List
       array.add(filescanner.next());
   }
   }
   //If file IOException is thrown
      catch(IOException ie)
   {
   System.out.println(ie);
   }String[] newArray = new String[array.size()];

   //Convert Array list to ArraynewArray=array.toArray(newArray);

   System.out.println("List of strings from file Before Sorting : \n");

   //Print before sorting words
   for(int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++)
   System.out.print(newArray[i]+" ");

   //Call sorting method
   sortArray(newArray);
   System.out.println("\nList of strings from file After Sorting : \n");

   //Print after sorting words
   for(int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++)
   System.out.print(newArray[i]+" ");

   System.out.print("\n");
   }
   else
       //If file name is not passed as argument then show usage syntax
       System.out.println("Usage syntax: SoftFile <example20_1.txt>");}
   }
   }
```

Comment: "I have no errors, but this program I wrote won't run"--Does that mean it won't compile, or that it produces no output when it runs, or something else?  Show us the compiler error, or whatever other error you see, so we have some idea of where the problem is.

Comment: it won't compile, there are no errors thrown or showing. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you get these words into your wordList from your text file

```
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        wordList.add("Ann");
        wordList.add("Sam");
        wordList.add("Peter");
        wordList.add("John");
        wordList.add("Watson");
```

**Method I:**
Your `sortArray` method should be updated to below :

```
  // you can call this method by sortArray(wordList.toArray(new String[wordList.size()]));
  public  String[] sortArray(String[] array) {
    int index;
    //Loop for no.of passes
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
        index = j;

        for (int i = j + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            //We keep track of the index to the smallest string
            if (array[i].trim().compareTo(array[index].trim()) < 0) {
                Index = i;
            }
        }
        //We only swap with the smallest string
        if (index != j) {
            String temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[index];
            array[index] = temp;
        }
    }
    return  array;//it returns the sorted array
}
```

you can check how it works by printing out the result using iterative loop

```
for (String arrayElement : your_array) {
            System.out.println(arrayElement);
        }
```

**Method II:**
This is how you going to sort these words easily in alphabetical order using java 8 lambda  expressions

```
    List<String> sortedList=wordList
                    .stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
            sortedList.forEach(i->System.out.println(i));
```

You will get the following out-put:

```
Ann
John
Peter
Sam
Watson
```